# Convert single value into multiple lines

Tags: sql, mysql, ms-access

i'm converting a database.
i have to convert a single column value (ie "bedrooms": 3) into multiple lines into another table
`bedroom | 1`
`bedroom | 1`
`bedroom | 1`

i'm using MS-Access to convert everything into a MySQL db, how can i do that?

Comment: What exactly is the rule for conversion? Do you have to understand English pluralization?

Comment: nono, it's quite simple. the word "bedroom" is an integer and a  link to another table. i put the word to explain what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a finite number of plural nouns, just write some VBA to use brute force.

pseudo code:

```
// suppose roomcount == bedrooms:3

room = whateverisbeforecolon (roomcount);  // bedrooms
count = whateverisaftercolon (roomcount);  // 3
if room = "bedrooms" then
begin
  for i = 1 to count do
     DoSomeSQL('insert into floorplan (listingnumber,roomtype,qty) values('1234','bedroom','1')');
end;
```